# Rails 5.1 generate resource is not creating default REST actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Very simple:

```
rails new myapp
cd myapp
rails generate resource Books title:string
```

Now look at app/controllers/books_controllers.rb and I find a two line class without any actions. From my reading of the doc, it seems to be expected to generate REST actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `rails generate resource` **does not** create any methods or views.

Try running

```
rails generate resource -h
```

You will see this

> Unlike the scaffold generator, the resource generator **does not** create
>   views or add any methods to the generated controller.

What you need is a `scaffold` generator

```
rails generate scaffold Book title:string
```

Comment: Yes, as you can see from the comment I posted above, I discovered the same thing!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct syntax that you must use is `scaffold` instead of `resource` this will create the controller, model and migration. To sum it up the code you must use is `rails generate scaffold Book title:string`

Pass an extra parameter `--skip-template-engine` if you do not want the views to be generated.

Comment: Not sure about that. What does rails generate resource do then?

Comment: try use `rails generate scaffold Book title:string`

Comment: using `resource` just plainly creates the files unlike using the `scaffold` its creates files with content read for the REST actions

Comment: use this `rails generate scaffold Book title:string`

Comment: "Unlike the scaffold generator, the resource generator does not create views or add any methods to the generated controller."

Comment: try passing an extra arguement `--skip-template-engine` this will not include the views if thats what you want `rails generate scaffold Book title:string --skip-template-engine`